# Uniq won't remove duplicate

Tags: command-line, curl, uniq

I was using the following command

```
curl -silent http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2919627 http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2919628 | grep node | awk '{print $3}' | uniq
```

when I wondered why `uniq` wouldn't remove the duplicates. Any idea why ?

Comment: Necro but with awk you don't need grep _or_ uniq: `| awk '/node/&&!dupe[$3]++{print $3}'` Also `curl` (like nearly all Unixy programs) needs _two_ dashes for a long-form option: `--silent` (or _short-form_ `-s`)

Comment: Related: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation#OSM_XML

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to sort the output in order for the `uniq` command to be able to work. See the man page:

> Filter adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

So you can pipe the output into `sort` first and then `uniq` it. Or you can make use of `sort`'s ability to perform the sort and unique all together like so:

```
$ ...your command... | sort -u
```

#### Examples

*sort | uniq*

```
$ cat <(seq 5) <(seq 5) | sort | uniq
1
2
3
4
5
```

*sort -u*

```
$ cat <(seq 5) <(seq 5) | sort -u
1
2
3
4
5
```

#### Your example

```
$ curl -silent http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2919627 http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2919628 \
      | grep node | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u
ref="1828989762"
ref="1829038636"
ref="1829656128"
ref="1865479751"
ref="451116245"
ref="451237910"
ref="451237911"
ref="451237917"
ref="451237920"
ref="451237925"
ref="451237933"
ref="451237934"
ref="451237941"
ref="451237943"
ref="451237945"
ref="451237947"
ref="451237950"
ref="451237953"
```

Comment: and what if I don't want the output to be sorted because my ordering matters? uniq cannot do that?

Comment: @Blauhirn no it cannot.

Comment: It cannot because it would be ineffiecient and unnecessary sometimes. The reason is that uniq looks at the previous and next line to figure out if it should keep the current entry. That makes the command run in `O(n)` time. If it had to sort the array first, it would be `O(n*nlogn)`, which would not always be necessary, so the command leaves the sorting up to you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short Python program which handles non-consecutive duplicate lines:

```py
import sys
cache = set()
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line in cache:
        continue
    cache.add(line)
    print(line, end="")
```

To use, pipe input into this Python script:

```bash
$ printf "3\n1\n4\n1\n4\n" | python unique.py
3
1
4
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove adjacent duplicate lines while retaining line order (that is, without sorting first) using the -u option:

```
uniq -u input.txt >output.txt
```

This is a bit odd, because reading the man page or the help it seems like it's saying it will only print the lines of the input file that are not duplicated, but that's not so. The -u option will print lines that are duplicated, but will output them just once, as well as lines that are not duplicated. It's badly worded, and I don't understand why this isn't the default behavior anyway. Odd. But it is what it is.

Comment: `uniq -u` prints a line every time it appears in the input without being _immediately_ preceded or followed by itself. If the input lines are `a` `b` `a` `a` `b` `a`, `uniq -u` outputs `a` `b` `b` `a` (i.e. `a` is only removed when it appears more than once _on adjacent lines_), which is unlikely to be the desired output here. Sure, the manual (the GNU one, at least) can easily be misread. `info uniq` (again, for the GNU utility) is a bit less terse.