# Why doesn't "uniq --unique" remove all duplicate lines?

Tags: uniq

Running

```
printf "lol\nlol\nfoo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nlol\nlol\nfoo\nlol\nfoo" | uniq --unique
```

prints

```
foo
bar
foo
lol
foo
```

Why is `foo` printed three times? Shouldn't `uniq --unique` remove them?

Also, notably, it seems all duplicates of `lol` were removed. Why were *lol* duplicates removed, but not *foo* duplicates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniq won't remove duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114140/uniq-wont-remove-duplicate)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`uniq` requires the input to be sorted (from `man uniq`) if you want it to remove *all* duplicate lines:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Filter adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing
> to OUTPUT (or standard output).

As you can see above, it only filters *adjacent* matching lines. This is why the `lol`s were removed. So sort your data before passing to `uniq`:

```
$ printf "lol\nlol\nfoo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nlol\nlol\nfoo\nlol\nfoo" | sort | uniq 

bar
foo
lol
```

Or, with GNU `sort`, skip `uniq`:

```
$ printf "lol\nlol\nfoo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nlol\nlol\nfoo\nlol\nfoo" | sort --unique

bar
foo
lol
```

Finally, if you want to completely remove lines that were present more than once (instead of keeping one copy, the default behavior), use `uniq -u` or `--unique` as in your question:

```
$ printf "lol\nlol\nfoo\n\n\n\n\nbar\nlol\nlol\nfoo\nlol\nfoo" | sort | uniq -u
bar
```

In all cases, however, the sorting is necessary.

Comment: thanks, somehow missed the meaning of `adjacent` in the docs; fwiw i ended up using `command | awk '!a[$0]++'` instead (because i wanted the first of each unique line without sorting it, seems that's what that odd-loking awk invocation does per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work )

Comment: @hanshenrik you're welcome. And yes, that `awk` works fine _for small datasets_. However, since it keeps an array entry for every non-duplicate line, that can cause problems if you try it on a huge dataset where the array might fill up your RAM. More than fine for regular sized datasets though, absolutely.

Comment: good point. if i need to do this on datasets so large that i don't want it all in ram, i guess... sqlite to the rescue? maybe (luckily im not in that situation now)

Comment: You can use `sort | uniq` on arbitrarily sized datasets. The only limit will be disk space, if I remember correctly, `sort` will create some temp files so that might fail if it fills up your disk, but apart from that you should be fine.

Comment: strictly speaking, `uniq` doesn't *require* the input to be sorted...but it only removes consecutive duplicate lines.  This can still be useful without sorting, e.g. if you want to reduce multiple blank lines between paragraphs down to just one blank line.   As @terdon says, though, if you want to get rid of dupes anywhere in the input, you'll need to sort it so that the all become adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking why `foo` is still in the list? `uniq` only removes adjacent repeated lines, "squeezing" the adjacent repeated lines into single lines.  With `-u` (or `--unique` with GNU `uniq`), it also removes lines that had adjacent repeated lines.

In you example, none of the three lines saying `foo` were ever adjacent to any other line saying `foo`. This is why they are outputted.

The `lol` lines that were removed were removed because they were adjacent to another line saying `lol`.   The last `lol` line was not duplicated in this sense, so it was kept.

Comment: thanks, somehow missed the meaning of `adjacent` in the docs, my bad